# Does it make sense to create both a label and a node with same name?

Tags: neo4j

For example, if iPhone is a brand, and iPhone 8 Plus is product, does it make sense to create two labels label 'iPhone' & 'SmartPhone', but at the same time to create iPhone alone as node, since iPhone as a brand has a few properties of its own:

```
create (p:iPhone:SmartPhone {name:"iPhone 8 Plus"}),
       (b:Brand {name:"iPhone", developer:"Apple", release:"2007"}),
       (p)-[:brand]->(b)
```

Does this sound redundant? Because "iPhone" is used both as a label and a node name. To find all iPhones, I can have:

```
Match (n:iPhone) return n
```

or

```
 Match (p:SmartPhone)-[:brand]->(b:Brand {name:"iPhone"}) return p;
```

Is this a good design? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should name them with common property like "Smartphone", So that you can query for a smartphone with name as iphone. It will actually depend on the schema and the type of data you have.

For example :
If you have a wide range of smartphones of different brands and different levels then it would be easy to search for a node labeled `smartphone` rather than particular brand.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean use "Smartphone" as a property instead of a label? By assigning two labels, iPhone and SmartPhone, I can quickly query on all iphones or all smartphones. Right?

Comment: yes. but not as property but `Smartphone` as a label to all the phones. Because querying using labels is faster than querying on a property.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid redundancy unless it is absolutely necessary. Redundancy requires more data storage, and can make it more difficult to maintain your data model because you have to make sure redundantly stored data is always consistent.

Besides, if you add an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Brand(name)`, your last Cypher example will be fast.

Comment: If I remove the label "iPhone" from p:iPhone:SmartPhone {name:"iPhone 8 Plus"}, the only way I get query all iPhones is through the second query, which should be much slower than the firs one, even if the index :Brand(name) is created?

Comment: for labels, do I need to create index, like iPhone(name) to get the speedup effect, or if I simply want to return all iPhones, I execute "Match (n:iPhone) return n", it doesn't matter whether I create index for the two labels iPhone and SmartPhone?

Comment: Your second query is a bit slower, but it should not be significantly slower. If you still wen with the label approach, no index is needed to get all iPhones.